# can I read data in java that is being generated from a hyperteminal device

Tags: java, serial-port, hyperterminal, comm

Is there any way I can read hyper-terminal data in JAVA to display it in a desktop software.
I am using hyper-terminal with a weighing machine connected with a port COMM 3.
I am not able to get how to read the data from it and how to display it into a screen of desktop software.

Answer (score 0):

normally you can read a hyper terminal like all other com Ports.
Same times you must send a specified symbol to the device. This you will find in 
in the device data sheet.

Here is an example to read a com Port.

[Com Port](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11)

Comment: I have tried the same code but 
portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); here the portList is null and that's why I am not able to run the code is there specific requirement or any configurations I have to make?

Comment: Show in the specification of your device.
I think you must send a init signal to ist to activate the Port.